# restricting context path is not working for Google Maps API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My original URL for an application to call Google Maps API is something like "https://example.com/abc/def" and I am trying to restrict the context path by replacing it with https://example.com/`*`. I have looked into so many references but nothing worked. I am facing the below error whenever I try replacing with '*' in context path.

```
Google Maps JavaScript API error: UnauthorizedURLForClientIdMapError
```

If I give whole path, then the API is loading with out any errors.

Comment: Are those really two `*` in the path?  I think if you look at the examples, there is only one.

Comment: I have tried with single, but some how while posting single star is getting ignored. Edited

Comment: What is the full path in the error message?

Comment: Google Maps JavaScript API error: UnauthorizedURLForClientIdMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#unauthorized-url-for-client-id-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: https://example.com/abc/def
(anonymous function) — js:60:134
(anonymous function) — common.js:75:365
(anonymous function) — common.js:151:179
c — common.js:69:86
Global Code — AuthenticationService.Authenticate:1

Comment: This error shows when I add * after the domain.

Comment: Is the `https:` in your "rule" but not the error message?

Comment: The rules I am using on `geocodezip.com` for all pages in that domain are: `*.geocodezip.com/*` and `geocodezip.com/*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205691/discussion-between-swetha-and-geocodezip).

Comment: @swetha Try adding the following two referrers: `https://example.com/*` and `https://*.example.com/*`. If the issue persists please contact Maps Tech Support https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support